# Set UILabel text from UITableView header section

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, tableheader

I've got an sectioned UITableView and want to set a label (not in the tableview) the text of the label that's on top.

I tried settings label with `[label setText:@"name"];` in

```
 (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

but that didn't work. Anyone else have ideas how to do this?

Comment: What delegate methods did u implement ?

Comment: I think, I wasn't that clear. I've got a UILabel of about 50x50 right on top of my view. I don't want tableHeaders but just the set the text on that label., now setting a static title on every header sectio

Answer (score 5):

Try this

```
-(UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    UIView *headerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 30, 60)];
    headerView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(0,0, 50, 50)];
    label.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
    label.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin;

    [headerView addSubview:label];
    return headerView;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're using that method you only need to return the string. It will handle creating a label for you.

```
- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return @"Name";
}
```

If you want to use your own `UIView` or `UILabel` you'll need to use a different `dataSource` method.

```
- (UIView *) tableview:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    UILabel *customLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRect(0.0,0.0,100.0,20.0)];
    [customLabel setText:@"name"];

    return customLabel;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    self.tableView1.tag = 1;
    if ( [tableView tag] == 1 ) {
        return @"TableView One Title";   
    }
    return @"other Tableview Title";        
}
```